# Video codec specs through ffmpeg (not being achieved)

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

The specs for the video format are the following:

- Aspect Ratio: 1:1
- H.264 video compression, high profile, square pixels, fixed frame rate, progressive scan
- .mp4 container with leading mov atom, no edit lists
- Audio: Stereo AAC audio compression, 128kbps +

Reading through posts and ffmpeg documentation I came up with the following (yeah, I run it on a Windows PC):

`ffmpeg.exe -r 30 -i input.webm -vf scale=iw*sar:ih -c:v libx264 -preset slow -profile:v high -c:a aac -strict experimental -ar 44100 -aspect 1:1 output.mp4`

But when the video is played within the app that asks for this specification, it only displays black moving pixels, all broken, but you an hear the audio.

I don't really know what else to change on the command, and I have no idea in regards to the **...with leading mov atom** specification.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I've tried @Mulvya's answer:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input.webm -vf scale=iw*sar:ih,setsar=1 -c:v libx264 -preset slow -profile:v high -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -c:a aac -strict experimental -ar 44100 -ac 2 -b:a 128k -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

But the effect is the same once given to the app:

[image: output of formatted video]

This is the information that ffmpeg spews about the input.webm file:

[image: ffmpeg info on input.webm]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input.webm -vf scale=iw*sar:ih,setsar=1 -c:v libx264 -preset slow -profile:v high -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -c:a aac -strict experimental -ar 44100 -ac 2 -b:a 128k -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Depending on how strict the app is, you may need to check the precise framerate. Use `-r 30000/1001` for `29.97`. The `-movflags +faststart` moves the moov atom to the front of the file.

---

Based on info I found elsewhere, this seems to be what Instagram requires:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input.webm -vf scale=640:640,setsar=1 -c:v libx264 -preset slow -profile:v main -level 3.1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30000/1001 -c:a aac -strict experimental -ar 44100 -ac 1 -b:a 64k -t 15 -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ( I did try the -r 30000/1001 option too), but the app keeps on displaying the video as in the added picture. So frustrating because on the preview, the video plays fine, it's after the app uploads it that it kills it.

Comment: Where are you publishing it?

Comment: Instagram. The specs are in Facebook.

Comment: [This](https://www.facebook.com/business/ads-guide/video-views/instagram-video-views/)? Seems to be for ads. In any case, what are the properties of input.webm?

Comment: It's part of the question now (the info ffmpeg tells me about the input.webm).

Comment: I figured it out, from the .webm output it stated that size was 638x638 . I fixed the scaling and added your command parameters for the mov part, it uploaded properly -- FINALLY! -- Thanks ;)